# What is the algorithm used by python's heapq.merge known as?

Tags: python, algorithm, merge, heap

From [python docs](https://docs.python.org/3.0/library/heapq.html#heapq.merge).

I have found the algorithm in quite a few places such as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5446254/3664835), [here](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/merge-k-sorted-arrays/) and [here](http://www.careercup.com/question?id=2261). None of them have mentioned the name of the algorithm.

I need to give a reference for a paper so please point me in the right direction.

Comment: This is a classic, and probably has no name, and is not python specific.

Comment: So can I just provide links as references? (I'm new to the field)

Comment: "Standard merge algorithm of sorted list using heaps"

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_algorithm

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is known as *"Multiway merging"* and is described by Donald Knuth in The Art of Computer Programming, Volume III - Sorting and Searching, section 5.4.1.

Comment: [Found it](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=cYULBAAAQBAJ&pg=PA251&lpg=PA251&dq=Multiway+merging+Donald+Knuth+in+The+Art+of+Computer+Programming,+Volume+III+-+Sorting+and+Searching,+section+5.4.1&source=bl&ots=KJysJgOn-K&sig=Tl_Ob26ILod8G7fzohdAqMyJFts&hl=en&sa=X&ei=QAdDVYffGYSwmAW8_YDAAQ&ved=0CC4Q6AEwAg#v=onepage&q=Multiway%20merging%20Donald%20Knuth%20in%20The%20Art%20of%20Computer%20Programming%2C%20Volume%20III%20-%20Sorting%20and%20Searching%2C%20section%205.4.1&f=false)

Comment: Great! Thanks for the name. I have Knuth sitting on my shelf, perhaps I should have looked first. (and yeah, +1!).

Answer (score 0):

If you understand merging of sorted lists then that is what this function is basically doing. There is no name for it, other than merging.

As an aside, merge-sort uses a similar routine, generally on two sorted lists. It is why it's called 'merge'-sort.